# Read a sheet from multiple xlsm files, manipulate each, then concatenate into one file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read multiple xlsm files, but just one specific sheet in each of them.

Then, I want to create a loop that would transform the data of each sheet into what I need it to be (each sheet gives 1 row) and then concat it all into one big file.

So something like:

```
for file in filenames:
df_temp = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='MySheet)
script of what I want to do
df_concat = pd.concat([df_temp for file in filenames]
```

I get stuck with reading in the data. This is what I've tried:

```
file_path='\\folder location'

filenames = glob.glob(file_path + "\[!~]*.xlsm", sheet_name='MySheet')
```

However, this gives an error:

```
TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheet_name'
```

How can I read in multiple xlsm sheets?

Answer (score 0):

You error is caused, by the fact that you passed an unwanted argument in your method that being the sheet_name argument.
If you want to read data from multiple xlsm sources. Even if they only contain a single row

Follow this logic

```
raw_path = r"E:\your_file\absolute path"
files = Path(raw_path).glob('*.xlsm')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for i in files],axis= 0)
```

The first line is the path to where you xlsm files are located, the files variable are just all the absolute paths to them. And well the concatenation is where you make your chunky dataframe.

Any doubts just tag